# How can I get the difference in the number of hours with a date from the future?

Tags: python, datetime

I have `datetime.now()` objects, and I want to know how many hours will pass before a specific hour the next day
I've tried this:

```
now = datetime.now()
then = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
then.hour = 12 # doesn't work
hours =  then - now
```

But I don't know how can I specify the exact hour for `then` object

Comment: I think this `timedelta(hours=1)` should work. Not sure about it

Comment: @ArpitSolanki This will add one hour, but it's not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand that you need. But you can try this

```
then = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1, hours=12)
```

or this

```
then = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
then.replace(hour=12)
```

If you need get diff in hour you should use

```
hours = (then - now).seconds // 3600
```

Comment: diff:
`hours.hour`

Comment: you'll need to do `then = then.replace(hour=12)` since the replace method doesn't modify the original object

Comment: Why is this different from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `timedelta` object will give you the total number of seconds between two times. The below will give you the number of whole hours between then and now.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
then = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
delta = then - now
hours = delta.total_seconds // 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you cannot specify particular hour for an existing `datetime` object, you can construct a future `datetime` object  explicitly using some attributes from `now`:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
then = datetime(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day+1, hour=19)
```